# How to Save a webpage as an image?

Tags: c#, winforms, webpage-screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically get screenshot of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981670/programmatically-get-screenshot-of-page)

What I am doing is a simple `WebBrowser1.Navigate("site");`

What I want to do is save a copy of that webpage that loads in my windows form WebBrowser1.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should be possible as WebBrowser is derived from Control.

This [link](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/04/screen-capture-using-wpf-winforms.html) explains how to get a screenshot from a winforms app.

Another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362525/c-winforms-getting-the-screenshot-image-that-has-to-be-behind-a-control) that might be useful

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the document as, e.g., an HTML file, the you can call the [WebBrowser.ShowSaveAsDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.showsaveasdialog.aspx) method.